# Hash login then search it with linq

Tags: linq, algorithm, entity-framework

I'm writing a piece of code with linq which has to hash a string (in that case my login) and then try to find it into my database.

I tried :

```
var userFind = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user =>HashHelper.HashCode(user.Login).Equals(u.Login));
```

I got an error because of the HashCode.
I wouldn't read all of my list with a foreach. I'm wondering if it's possible to do so with one line of code.
Regards.

Edit: I found a way to do so, but it isn't as lighter as I expected.

```
  User userFind = null;
            foreach (var user in context.Users)
            {
                string hashedLogin = HashHelper.HashCode(user.Login);
                if(hashedLogin.Equals(u.Login))
                {
                    userFind = user;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is `u.Login` and why are you hashing the values from the database?

Comment: Ah, I See, so `u.Login` is a hashed Login you want to match. Unhashed logins are stored in the database. The problem you have is that `HashHelper.HashCode` has no obvious translation to TSQL so any ORM would not be able to translate it to SQL. Is this right?

Comment: Your edit acually pulls all users to the client and does the comparison where `HashHelper.HashCode` can be evaluated. If you don't have lots of users (1000+ approx) this is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: @Jodrell Thx, I will do that way. And I will maybe  change it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have too many users, you can do it on one line like this.

```
var userFind = context.Users.ToList().FirstOrDefault(
    user => HashHelper.HashCode(user.Login).Equals(u.Login))
```

The important bit is the `ToList()` which evaluates the EF part and makes the rest linq-to-objects. This means the comparison will be done on the client and all users will be retrieved from the server. It is equivalent to your edit.

If performance is a problem you should store the hashcode in the database too.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the database is already hashed and u.Login is the value of the current user's login, then you could probably do it like this:

```
var hashedLogin = HashHelper.HashCode(u.Login); // hash the value in the app so it can be compared to already hashed values in database.
var userFind = context.Users.Where(user => user.Login == hashedLogin).FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't really know much about what you're trying to achieve, so I'll be pleasantly surprised if this actually helps. Good luck!